# how to create django edit test and update test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

```
I have views.py like this
```

and than how to create edit test and update test?? i 
want edit and update can do it by id
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .models import People

```
def index(request):
    peoples = People.objects.all()
    context = {'peoples': peoples}
    return render(request, 'people_app/index.html', context)

def create(request):
    print(request.POST)
    people_app = People(name=request.POST['name'], biography=request.POST['biography'])
    people_app.save()
    return redirect('/')

def edit(request, id):
    people = People.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'people': people}
    return render(request, 'people_app/edit.html', context)

def update(request, id):
    people = People.objects.get(id=id)
    people.name = request.POST['name']
    people.biography = request.POST['biography']
    people.save()
    return redirect('/')

def destroy(request, id):
    people = People.objects.get(id=id)
    people.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit or Update operations performed in POST request. As you have write definition based view you have to check for type of request and act accordingly.

```
def edit(request, id):
    people = People.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        people.<field_to_update> = request.POST.get('<field_value>')
        people.save()
    context = {'people': people}
    return render(request, 'people_app/edit.html', context)
```